# FindBugs and jMock interaction

Tags: java, findbugs, jmock

Somewhere in a test, we're mocking something out using jMock.

```
    mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{
        allowing(thing).getProperty(); will(returnValue(something));
    }});
```

FindBugs unhelpfully complains about this:

```
MyTest.java:86, RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_NO_SIDE_EFFECT, Priority: Normal
```

Its help text says to put `@CheckReturnValue` on the method to suppress it, but the method is not in our API, but some API which we integrate with.

Is there an elegant way to resolve this warning?

(i.e., without using the sledgehammer approach of suppressing the check, which might also suppress it for actual bugs.)